# GEE contradicts descriptives

Tags: generalized-estimating-equations

I'm writing my thesis on the effects of tobacco control policies on tobacco cognitions. One of the cognitions is pro-smoking health beliefs and is a dependent variable in a binary generlized estmimation equation.

**Descriptives**

Over time, that is after policy implementation, the percentage of people reporting pro-tobacco cognitions decreases (31.4% pre-policy implementation vs 21.1% post-policy implementation).

**GEE**

The results of the binary GEE show a significant increase in odds for reporting pro smoking health beliefs. (OR=1.84 95%CI=1.19-2.83)

My question is, how come that the descriptives show a strong decrease oafter policy implementation while the GEE suggest the opposite.

Thank you for reading my question.

Kind regards,

Eli